# Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlacesClient'

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places

I'm trying to implement Google *Auto complete* service and, I get this message:

> Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlacesClient'

I imported *Google Maps* module and it works with GMSMapView...
I don't understand what is happening.
Does anyone have the same error?
This is a picture of the error:

[image: ErrorImage]

[image: ErrorImage]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the problem. Google has divided his API in two parts. Last release splits the Places API from the Maps SDK (since Version 2.0.0 - July 26, 2016).  You can find it in the release notes: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/releases?hl=es

Comment: But posting a link to the docs is not a direct solution to the original error we receive in XCode, `Use of undeclared type 'GMSPlacesClient'`...

Comment: Plus that is a 404 link...

Answer (score 18):

I have also face the same issue. To resolve this I have add pod `GooglePlaces` in my pod file and update the pod.

Also you need to replace import `import GoogleMaps` To `import GooglePlaces`

Comment: I've done this and it didn't resolve the problem

Answer (score 2):

I bumped the same problem recently.
It seems that the reason of issue is updated GoogleMap library. They changed their API.
My solution was just return to the previous version of GoogleMaps. For me the working version is 1.13.2.

If you want to specify the v1.13.2 you can put it to the Podfile:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '~> 1.13.2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>
```

into

> TSTHelmet-Bridging-Header.h

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal, cd to your project folder and run pod update, or better yet pod update --verbose.